# Primefaces fileDownload JavaScript Error

Tags: jsf, primefaces, icefaces

I'm trying to Download a File with the Primefaces fileDownload component. Unfortunately it is not working. I only get an Javascript Error "[window] the response does not contain XML data"

I am using JSF 2.1.6 with Primefaces 3.2, IceFaces Push version 2.0.2 is used to Push data, and some Spring Functions with Spring Version 3.1.0. All Running on a Tomcat 6.0.33.

A Snippet of my xHtml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
 <p:layout> 
   ...
   <p:layoutUnit id="east" ... >
     <h:form id="eForm">
       <p:dataTable ... >
         ...
           <p:row >
             <p:column style="font-weight: bold;">Attach 1:</p:column>
               <p:column>
                 <p:commandLink id="attach1" value="Download" ajax="false" immediate="true">
                      <p:fileDownload value="#{data.file}" />
                    </p:commandLink> 
                  </p:column>
                </p:row>
       </p:dataTable>
     </h:form>
    ...
 </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

The FileDownload Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name = "data")
@RequestScoped
public class FileDownload {

private StreamedContent file;

public FileDownload() {
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/resources/images/phone_speaker_x24.png");
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");
}

public StreamedContent getFile() {
    return file;
}
}
```

The Error from FireBug

```
 [window] the response does not contain XML data  bridge...9208334 (Zeile 1217)
 [window] Error [status: emptyResponse code: 200]: An empty response was received from the server. Check server error logs.
```

There is no Error at the Tomcat Log

**Edit**

Icefaces is the Problem. Removing all Icefaces Libs the Download works fine. But no IceFaces no Push so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, Primefaces and IcePush don't allways work together. Removing the IceFaces Push from my Project made the Download work but no Push.

So i decided to write the Push on my own and just use Primefaces.

Answer (score 0):

if you put a breakpoint in the getFile method, is the file==null?

The problem could be that your class is not well constructed

Comment: File != null, so thats not the Problem